# Effects on upgrading to 12.04 LTS on ROS-related stuff

Tags: ros-fuerte, ubuntu, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have 3 questions regarding upgrading Ubuntu version and its effect on ROS:

1. If I upgrade from 10.04(LTS) to 12.04(LTS), will Electric be maintained or is it automatically upgraded to Fuerte?
2. Will my developed nodes that run under Electric be working out of the box under Feurte?
3. Is it wise to upgrade to 12.04 for ROS-dependent development?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38911/effects-on-upgrading-to-12.04-lts-on-ros-related-stuff/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-07-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. ROS Electric is not released for Ubuntu 12.04. So I guess that an upgrade will remove your Electric installation. If not, it will be broken for sure and you'll have to uninstall it from hand.
2. We didn't have too many issues. We had some minor issues with TF datatypes since tf::Vector3 and friends are different from the corresponding bullet data types now, i.e. tf data types and bullet data types cannot be mixed anymore. The fix was not much more than a simple search-and-replace in all files that threw compilation errors. All other problems we had were caused by the newer PCL version. I'd say if you don't heavily use PCL, the upgrade shouldn't break too much.
3. I'd say it depends. If you still need Electric, I would wait with the upgrade. Otherwise, I would do it.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4